Did Ram and Laxman hunt in the forest and consume meat?
What does the unabridged Ramayana have to say? Did they (as Kashatriyas) really hunt and consume meat while they were in exile?

This question is similar to: Was Lord Rama a non-vegetarian?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
